# Passing an array of fstreams to a function?

Tags: c++, fstream

I am basically writing this:-

```
void function(fstream& f[], int m){
// using fstream objects
}

int main()
{
    int m = 4;
    fstream f[m];
    f[0].open("f0.txt");
    f[1].open("f1.txt");
    f[2].open("f2.txt");
    f[3].open("f3.txt");

    function(f, m);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors that are coming:-

```
error: declaration of ‘f’ as array of references|
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token|
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’|
```

All these errors are at line

```
void function(fstream& f[], int m){
```

If I just initialise the fstream array inside the function, the errors go away. What should I do to remove the errors if I initialise them in the main function?

Comment: I think you want `fstream* f` as the argument. Remember that arrays naturally decays to *pointers* (to their first element).

Comment: Why do you want to code that? Notice that `fstream`-s don't know their file path! Your question shows a lot of confusion (at several places), so you probably should **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are trying to pass a pointer to reference, not an array. To solve this problem you should pass a real pointer `fstream *` or (better) use ::std::array instead:

```
using t_FileStreams = ::std::array<::std::fstream, 4>;

void sort(t_FileStreams & streams){
// using fstream objects
}

int main()
{
    t_FileStreams f;
    f[0].open("f0.txt");
    f[1].open("f1.txt");
    f[2].open("f2.txt");
    f[3].open("f3.txt");

    sort(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to use `std::vector<::std::fstream>` if amount of items is not known at advance. Also note that code `int m = 4; fstream f[m];` is not legal in C++ because array size must be a constant known at compile time.

Comment: It is giving an error:-  error: ‘array’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type|

Comment: @firstlegagain1 You need to include corresponding standard library header, just like for any other standard library class. `#include <array>`

Comment: Notice that the OP won't be able to write his own `sort` function, because `fstream`-s are not comparable

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch For example they can be compared based on file content or file size.

Comment: But the question suggests to compare file paths. And `std::fstream` has no compare operations at all and are *not* [LessThanComparable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LessThanComparable)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Don't you think that OP is actually not trying to sort those streams but trying to sort content of files?

Comment: Even if the OP wants to sort file contents, he should get that content *before* the sort, not in the compare function. We don't exactly know what the OP wants, but his approach is flawed in all  cases.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using some standard [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), probably [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Read about the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). You can pass a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to it giving the compare criteria.

You cannot easily compare [`std::fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream)-s, because they don't keep their [file path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)). Once you have given some path to an `fstream` (by [`open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) or at [construction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) time), that path is lost. You need to keep it *explicitly* by yourself.

If you wanted to compare file by some other criteria (e.g. their contents), you'll better [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) that criteria (e.g. keep their content in some separate data). Any sorting functions would need to compare elements *several* times (since the sorting complexity is *at least* O(n log n)....), so doing IO in the compare function is unreasonable. Likewise, if you want to compare files by some metadata such as their size and/or creation time, better retrieve that metadata once (e.g. using [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on Linux) before the sort.

Perhaps you want to define your own `class` or `struct` which keeps both a `std::string` and a [smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) (e.g. some [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)) to some `std::fstream`.

You'll then pass by reference, or by `const` reference, a container of such objects to your function.

Before coding spend several days reading a [good book on C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/).

Notice that IO operations are generally [very slow](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers). They might last several milliseconds each (while most CPU operations take only nanoseconds). So it is usually unreasonable to do IO in the compare code passed to some sort function.

Comment: Indeed, but spending first a few days reading a good book will earn you weeks of useless work. See also http://norvig.com/21-days.html; it looks like you are missing the basics. Why do you think that `fstream`-s are comparable?

Answer (score 0):

To pass an arbitrary-sized array to a function you can use an array reference (which are declared like `Type(&Identifier)[Size]`) and a template like so.

```
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N>
void sort(std::ifstream(&ins)[N]) { /* implementation */ }
```

`N` is the size of the array `ins`, and can be used within the function body of `sort` as if it were a normal parameter.

If the array is only ever going to be one size you can leave off the template.

```
void sort(std::ifstream(&ins)[4]) { /* implementation */ }
```

This also works with `std::array`.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N>
void sort(std::array<std::ifstream, N> &ins) { /* implementation */ }
```